# Adding a Universal Windows C# Class Library reference to a Universal Windows C++ DLL project Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, uwp

As the title describes, I am trying to add a UWP C# class library reference to a UWP C++ DLL project. Both projects are targeting Windows 10 v10.0.14393.0.  When the reference is added, everything appears to be valid and the reference shows up under the reference list with no errors listed.  When you try to use the reference and compile, the following error is given:

> C2871  a namespace with this name does not exist.

Am I missing something here? The only options when creating a new Universal Windows C++ project are DLL, Static Lib, and Windows Runtime Component.  There is not a class library option for C++.  I tried all three different projects with the same outcome.  Can someone please provide a solution and/or explain why I am not able to reference a UWP C# class library from a UWP C++ project?  This seems like something that should be possible. I know it has been possible in the past, prior to UWP.

Code is simple.

C# Code:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

C++ Code:

```
using namespace ClassLibrary1;
```

Comment: It'll likely be a setting, please confirm things like targeting both to x86 and signing assemblies results in the same compilation error

Comment: Both projects are set to x64 under the configuration manager (Release x64 build).  Not sure how to check the signing assembly results?

Comment: So targeting x86 results in same error? Have you tried using different namespacrs? Like ClassLibCSharp & ClassLibCpp? Signing is a very long shot and more of an example on things to try to get more clues but try it, the Signing tab is in the Project Properties

Comment: When selecting x86, the dll is setup for Win32 while the c# project is x86.  I think this is equivalent?

Comment: [Creating Windows Runtime Components in C# and Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/creating-windows-runtime-components-in-csharp-and-visual-basic) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C# project has to be a "C# Windows Runtime Component" project, rather than "C# Class Library". You cannot access class libraries from C++. If target code is in a different language, the most practical way is to access it by compiling it to a Windows Runtime Component.

Also, after making C# Windows Runtime Component project, don't forget to add it to your C++ project references (/FU compiler flag if you're not using vcxproj to build your code).

Comment: Set it up as a runtime component instead but I am still getting the same error:   Error C2871 'RuntimeComponent1': a namespace with this name does not exist WindowsRuntimeComponent1

Comment: I was able to get this to work by making both the C++ and C# projects run-time components.  If one or the other is not a run-time component you will get the namespace does not exist error.